# StringIndexOutOfBounds exception

Tags: android, string, indexing

Google Play tells me that this error is happening some times in my app and I don't have an idea about how to fix it. As there's the Stack trace, I can see where in my code it happens.
Do you see my error?

```
public static String formatNumber(Context context, String number) {

    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String localNumber = preferences.getString(Constants.NUMBER_PREFERENCE, "No Stored Number");
    number = number.replaceAll("[^0-9+]", "");

    if (number.charAt(0) == '+')
        return number;

    try {

        PhoneNumberUtil util = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
        PhoneNumber localNumberObject = util.parse(localNumber, null);

        String localCountryCode = util.getRegionCodeForNumber(localNumberObject);
        Log.w("PhoneNumberFormatter", "Got local CC: " + localCountryCode);

        PhoneNumber numberObject = util.parse(number, localCountryCode);
        return util.format(numberObject, PhoneNumberFormat.E164);
    } catch (NumberParseException e) {

        Log.w("PhoneNumberFormatter", e);
        return impreciseFormatNumber(number, localNumber);
    }
}
```

Thanks

EDIT: The error is being caused by line 80 (which is line 1 here)

```
if (number.charAt(0) == '+')
  return number;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that could be causing it in the posted code is `charAt()` in the following line

```
if (number.charAt(0) == '+')
```

which means you don't have a valid number after formatting with the regex.

To fix this, you could wrap it in a `try/catch` then, assuming `number` comes from an `EditText` or similar, display a message to the user that something is invalid

```
try {
    if (number.charAt(0) == '+')
        return number;
}
catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    // display message here
}
```

Instead of displaying a message there, you may actually want to return say a -1 and then do something with it in the calling method depending on the return value.

[charAt() Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int))

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the input is but it's got to be the number.charAt(0) that is causing the issue so that means number is an empty string so I'm betting after the following line that number is an empty string. I hope that helps.

```
number = number.replaceAll("[^0-9+]", "");
```

Comment: What he means is that, if passed a string like "-a" the `replaceAll()` would give you a string back as "" (empty string) in which case there is NO charAt(0) .. thus giving you your StringIndexOutOfBounds Error .. You might consider assigning a default value after the replaceAll if it's an empty string (something like `if empty string then set string = "0"`) .. it depends on how you want the method to behave.

Comment: So I should replace the second with a zero?